# Slide down animation for react modal

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog, css-animations, css-transitions

I have implemented a modal in react and css, currently, when I open it I have implemented a sliding up animation in which the modal slides up from the bottom, but when I close it i want it slide down, I'm not able to figure out as to how do you exactly create that slide down animation, can somebody please help,
code =>

```
import "./styles.css";
import react, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(true)}>open </button>
      {isModalOpen && (
        <div className={`modal-overlay`}>
          <div className={`modal-content`}>
            <div className="feedbackModalHeader">
              <img
                src="/assets/dislike_modal.svg"
                alt=""
                className="dislikeBtnNonFilled"
              />
              <p className="provideFeedback">Provide additional feedback</p>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(false)}> close </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

css code =>

```
.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

* {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.modal-content {
  background: #f5f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index: 999;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  animation: slide-up 0.3s ease-out forwards;
  width: 59rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 6%);
  height: 21rem;
  position: relative;
  left: 2rem;
}

@keyframes slide-up {
  from {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.provideFeedback {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.feedbackModalHeader {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
}
```

code sandbox link =>
https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-river-6ckllv?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 2):

Building off of user20459171's answer. You need a conditional class name. However since you are starting from the center of the screen to the bottom, the transform goes from 0 to a 100%. The proper css is this:

```
.modal-overlay {
position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

* {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.modal-content {
  background: #f5f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index: 999;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  width: 59rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow:
    0 4px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%),
    0 1px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 6%);
  height: 21rem;
  position: relative;
  left: 2rem;
}

.modal-content.slide-down {
  animation: slide-down 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.modal-content.slide-up {
  animation: slide-up 0.5s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-down {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-up {
  from {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.provideFeedback {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.feedbackModalHeader {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
}
```

I've separated the animation code into its own class name. One for going up and one for going down. As well I mentioned earlier I added the @keyframes slide-down with the proper from and to transitions. Here is the app.js file.

```
    import "./styles.css";
    import react, { useState } from "react";
    
    export default function App() {
        const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
        //This useState Hook sets the animation to the correct direction
        const [modalAnimation, setModalAnimation] = useState("slide-up");
    
        function close() {
            setModalAnimation("slide-down");
            setTimeout(() => {
                setIsModalOpen(false);
                // Sets it for the next time so it slides up when called
                setModalAnimation("slide-up");
            }, 600);
        }
    
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(true)}>open </button>
                {isModalOpen && (
                    <div className={`modal-overlay`}>
                        <div className={`modal-content ${modalAnimation}`}>
                            <div className="feedbackModalHeader">
                                <img
                                    src="/assets/dislike_modal.svg"
                                    alt=""
                                    className="dislikeBtnNonFilled"
                                />
                                <p className="provideFeedback">Provide additional feedback</p>
                            </div>
                            <button onClick={() => close()}> close </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
                   
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I also made the timeout 600ms so that it is much smoother.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the modal's classes based on the *state*. (**A conditional class name**)

Here is a simple way to create a modal with the things you want:

First, define the CSS animation:

```
.modal-slide-down {
  animation-name: slide-down;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Then, in your React component, add a state variable to track whether the modal should be open or closed:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
```

When the user clicks a button or performs some other action to open the modal, set the isOpen state to true:

```
<button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Open Modal</button>
```

Finally, conditionally apply the CSS class to the modal based on the isOpen state:

```
<div className={`modal ${isOpen ? 'modal-slide-down' : ''}`}>
  {/* Modal content goes here */}
</div>
```

**A little more explanation:**

When the `isOpen` state is true, the `modal-slide-down` class is added to the modal component, which triggers the slide-down animation. When the `isOpen` state is false, the `modal-slide-down` class is removed, which triggers the slide-up animation.

With these changes, the modal will slide down into view when it is opened and slide back up when it is closed. Of course, you may need to adjust the animation duration and other CSS properties to fit your specific use case.

I hope I was able to solve your problem.